# Cut and paste a row (based on a cell value) into a certain sheet, which is also based on a different cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet that I've made to track progress on projects. I currently have an active x button that when clicked it moves a row from the active worksheet (Project Tracker) to another worksheet (Released). The value that would trigger this action would be in column J (Released). This works perfectly.

I would like to have multiple worksheets that have the same names as the project names which are based on different companies that would be selected from a drop-down list (to stop typos). I need help on code to move the cut rows to these certain sheets.

Current code:

`enter code here`

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim I As Long
    Dim J As Long
    Dim K As Long
    DIM T AS

    I = Worksheets("PROJECT TRACKER").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    J = Worksheets("RELEASED").UsedRange.Rows.Count

    If J = 1 Then
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("RELEASED").UsedRange) = 0 Then J = 0
    End If

    Set xRg = Worksheets("PROJECT TRACKER").Range("L1:L" & I)

    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For K = 1 To xRg.Count
        If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "RELEASED" Then
            xRg(K).EntireRow.Cut Destination:=Worksheets("RELEASED").Range("A" & J + 1)
            xRg(K).EntireRow.Delete
            If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "RELEASED" Then
                K = K - 1
            End If
            J = J + 1
        End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

his is cross-posted
https://www.excelguru.ca/forums/showthread.php?10476-Cut-and-Paste-a-row-in-one-sheet-to-another-based-on-a-cell-value

Comment: Please format your code. When you edit your question there is an icon {} which allows you to format a whole block of text as code

Comment: First of all you need to remove `On Error Resume Next` this line hides **all** error massages until `End Sub` but the errors still occur. You just cannot see their messages. So if you don't see the messages you cannot fix you errors and if you don't fix them your code obviously cannot work properly. Remove the line and tell which errors you get and where. • If error handline is needed you might benefit from reading [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling)

Comment: I am so sorry about the edit. This was my first post and I didn't do it correctly. Lesson learned. I removed On Error Resume Next and did not get any errors. This code works fine for me.

Comment: I still don't get what is wrong with your code then? What is your question? Please be more specific when describing it, give examples (incl. some example data) or screenshots. Show what your data looks like and what you want to achieve. •  Note that if you delete or cut rows your loop must be reverse `For K = xRg.Count To 1 Step -1` otherwise the row count changes also if you already `.Cut` a row you don't need to `.Delete` it it gets automatically "moved".